# Updating Nan Values in CSV file using pandas with if else condition on other column of CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update the Nan values in Age column based on class of the person.The csv file contain Age and class of person.
If the person is of 1st class his age is 35.
If the person is of 2nd class his age is 30.
If the person is of 3rd class his age is 25.

```
Csv File
Age   Class
32     2
26     3
Nan    1
36     1
24     3
Nan    2
Nan    3


Update Csv File
Age   Class
32     2
26     3
35     1
36     1
24     3
30     2
25     3
```

I have tried some pandas function but it did not worked.

```
df[ (df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Pclass==1) ]['Age'] = 35
df[ (df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Pclass==2) ]['Age'] = 30
df[ (df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Pclass==3) ]['Age'] = 25
```

Please provide a solution....

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is a standard pandas question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
age_dict={1:35, 2:30, 3:25}

# read csv
df = pd.read_csv('in_file.csv')

# update the missing ages
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df['Class'].map(age_dict))

# save csv
df.to_csv('out_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy:

```
df['Age'] = np.where((df.Age.isnull() == True) & (df.Pclass==1), 35, df['Age])
df['Age'] = np.where((df.Age.isnull() == True) & (df.Pclass==2), 30, df['Age])
df['Age'] = np.where((df.Age.isnull() == True) & (df.Pclass==3), 25, df['Age])
```

Comment: Don't forget to:

import pandas as pd

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this should work,

```py
df['Age'][ df['Age'].isnull() & df['lass'] == 1] = 35
df['Age'][ df['Age'].isnull() & df['lass'] == 2] = 30
df['Age'][ df['Age'].isnull() & df['lass'] == 3] = 25
```

Answer (score 0):

First Convert the csv file as shown below before importing to pandas:

```
Age,Class
32,2
26,3
,1
36,1
24,3
,2
,3
```

Now import the csv file and assign values to Nan.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(YOUR_CSV_FILE)
df.loc[ (df.Age.isna()) & (df.Class==1) ] = 35,1
df.loc[ (df.Age.isna()) & (df.Class==2) ] = 30,1
df.loc[ (df.Age.isna()) & (df.Class==3) ] = 25,1
```